# Android Bluetooth Service disable

Tags: android, bluetooth, telephony

A small part of my application is designed to work with any car radio. The problem I have is that if the user is already bluetooth paired with the car and they add a new contact, it does not sync on the car unless the bluetooth connection is reset (the address book is redwonloaded to the car).

The only way Ive been able to achieve this is to quickly enable and disable bluetooth but that takes too long. Is there a particular service I can disable some sort of telephony service and then re-enable it so that the car picks up the new contacts?

This happens on most cars btw.

If anyone has an idea please let me know. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Bluetooth connection just needs a nudge - something to awaken the connection.

How about creating a dummy connection to one of the service's that are listed by the car's Bluetooth.  Figure out the UUID for one of the car's services and then do a socket.connect to that UUID.